# Laravel - passing variable to partial

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using the same partial twice in the app layout. I am passing the variable like so:

```
<body>

  <div class="background-container">
    <img src="{{ asset('/img/cover_art.jpg') }}" alt="" />
  </div>

  @section('topBar')
    @include('customer.layouts.partials.top-bar')
  @show

  <div class="panel">

    @section('carousel')
      @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['section' => 'header-carousel'])
    @show
  </div>

  <div class="container">

      @section('magazine-detail')
        @include('customer.layouts.partials.magazine-detail')
      @show
      <div class="show-for-medium">
        @section('carousel')
          @include('customer.layouts.partials.carousel', ['section' => 'footer-carousel'])
        @show
      </div>

  </div>

  @section('scripts')
    @include('customer.layouts.partials.scripts')
  @show

</body>
```

And then in the partial I am getting the variable like so:

```
<section class="carousel {{ $section }}">
```

The problem is that I get the same value for both partials, the `header-carousel`. How can I fix that?
This is the stripped down html output:

```
<nav class="side-nav">
</nav>
<section class="top-bar">
  ...
</section>

<section class="carousel header-carousel">
  ...
</section>
<section class="row magazine-detail">
    ...
</section>

<section class="carousel header-carousel">
  ...
</section>
```

Comment: Can you provide the html output of the end result (trimmed down to just the div and section classes of interest)? Also, is there any script which uses a $section variable besides the partials and this main template you posted? There might be a scoping issue going on.

Comment: I have added the html output to the question. I am not using $section variable in any other place, so not sure why is this happening.

Comment: @Leff you're basically setting the same section `carousel` two times. Post your layout file that you extend, or just make sure you use different sections for both the items.

Comment: Do you have a documented example you can work from which sets different variables for the same partial used on the same page load? Maybe the framework doesn't support this. That's the only thing I can think of. Usually, a partial is loaded just once per page, but reused across many pages. I'm not sure if the devs of this framework thought of your use case.